# @ControllerAdvice не отлавливает исключение?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Здравствуйте нужна помощь.
Есть кастомное исключение.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class AuthenticationException extends RuntimeException{
    private final HttpStatus httpStatus;
    private final String message;
    private final String value;
    private final ErrorCode errorCode;

    public AuthenticationException(String message, String value, HttpStatus httpStatus){
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
        this.message = message;
        this.value = value;
        this.errorCode = null;
    }

    public AuthenticationException(String message, String value, HttpStatus httpStatus, ErrorCode errorCode){
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
        this.message = message;
        this.value = value;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public AuthenticationException(String message, HttpStatus httpStatus){
        this.httpStatus = httpStatus;
        this.message = message;
        this.value = null;
        this.errorCode = null;
    }
}
```

также есть место где это исключение выбрасывается

```
 public ProfileSessionDTO getSessionBySessionId(String sessionId){
        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(sessionId)) {
            throw new AuthenticationException("Хэдер сессии не может быть пустым", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }

        return authenticationClient.sessionBySessionId(sessionId);
    }
```

есть перехватчик исключений. При вызове этого исключения, в ответ приходит код ошибки 500 с моим сообщением. Хотя я жду 400 код ошибки. Я пробовал Ловить все исключения. @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class). Но программа не попадает в мой ApplicationExceptionHandler

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<AuthenticationExceptionResponseDTO> authenticationExceptionHandler(AuthenticationException e, HttpServletRequest request) {
        AuthenticationExceptionResponseDTO response = createErrorResponse(e.getHttpStatus(), e.getMessage(), request.getRequestURI(), e.getValue());
        response.setErrorCode(e.getErrorCode());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, e.getHttpStatus());
    }
}
```

Я смотрел много информации и много попробовал.
Пока я не могу решить свою задачу.
Варианты которые я пробовал

1. @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
2. 

```
@Bean
   public ErrorPageFilter errorPageFilter() {
       return new ErrorPageFilter();
   }

   @Bean
   public FilterRegistrationBean disableSpringBootErrorFilter(ErrorPageFilter filter) {
       FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
       filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(filter);
       filterRegistrationBean.setEnabled(false);
       return filterRegistrationBean;
   }
```

3.@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)

Я буду рад любой помощи.

Пример ответа

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-09-28T13:13:17.342+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Хэдер сессии не может быть пустым",
    "path": "/ses"
}
```

Comment: Еще идеи - может вместо своего AuthenticationException импортнулся какой-нибудь спринговый? Или ComponentScan настроен так, что спринг не находит ApplicationExceptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

`AuthenticationException` такое исключение есть у `Spring Security` в пакете `org.springframework.security.core`. Проверьте импорты как минимум. В дебаг режиме, программа входит в необходимые контрольные точки? Если есть возможность, предоставьте ссылку на репозиторий, чтобы взглянуть более подробно.

Comment: Спасибо, импорты проверил, там всё в порядке. В режиме дебаг программа не заходит в ApplicationExceptionHandler, даже если я пытаюсь поймать все исключения. Извините репозиторий зпкрыт(

Comment: После того как исключение выбрасывается его перехватывает ExceptionTranslationFilter. Может есть идеи как изменить порядок вызова фильтров?

Comment: Ещё дополнение это всё происходит в Zuul